# rsync via ssh password prompt question

Tags: networking, ssh, rsync, radius

Hi I have an rsync shell script that synchronizes one host with a remote host:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -avz fqdn:/foo/dir1
rsync -avz fqdn:/foo/dir2
rsync -avz fqdn:/foo/dir3
```

The remote host permits the rsync without a password with ssh pre shared keys but only when the above script uses the fully qualified domain, if I reference the IP of the remote host like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -avz 192.168.1.1:/foo/dir1
rsync -avz 192.168.1.1:/foo/dir2 
rsync -avz 192.168.1.1:/foo/dir3
```

It will prompt me for a password for the remote host, why does it behave like this?

Ideally I want the IP reference in the case that the host can't resolve the remote host.

Comment: Does your SSH client configuration set the keys used for the host?

Comment: In the autorization file of the user@host (usually `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) there might be the key option `from=`, which "Specifies that in addition to public key authentication, either the canonical name of the remote host or its IP address must be present in the comma-separated list of patterns." (see `man sshd`).

Comment: @muru There is currently no ssh config so I will say 'no'

Comment: @ridgy thanks for your input, it does make sense I see in 'authorized_keys' the hostname referenced next to the ssh key rather than the IP address!